# After updating to OS X 10.5.8 and updating Fink, Texmax stoped working

Tags: macos, installation, fink

I know just enough about installing UNIX like software on my Mac to get into trouble and this time I messed up all my software.  I use Octive, Texmax, emacs and was playing with NGSpice.  The history of what I did is as follows:

I used FinkCommander to install Octive, Texmax, emacs and NGSpice.  All worked OK.
I updated my PowerBook G4 to OS X 10.5.8.  The Mac worked OK.
I used FinkCommander to update the packages.  I ran Update-All.  This is when the problems started.

The error message is like;

Failed to fetch http://msn.wi.us.finkmirrors.net/mirrors/fink/finkbindist/bindist/dists/fink-0.9.0/main/binary-darwin-powerpc//base/fink-obsolete-packages_0.1-1_darwin-powerpc.deb  404 Not Found

Is this a problem with Fink?

When I updated my OS to 10.5.8, I did not update my Xcode.  I am having a hard time finding the link to Xcode 3.0 or 3.1.  I understand these are the versions I need to use.

I need to know what is the fastest way to get my software working?

Answer (score 3):

Try "Self update Rsync" under Source; that should update your mirrors. About Fink mirrors: [Fink - F.A.Q. - Mirrors](http://www.finkproject.org/faq/mirrors.php)

XCode 3.1.2 is at [Apple ADC Member](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20262)